# Error during Forest OpenFermion installation

Tags: programming, openfermion, pyquil, rigetti

I tried installing Forest OpenFermion by
`pip install forestopenfermion` and I got the following long error message (cut):

```
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Building wheel for scipy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/michelle/anaconda/envs/py3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jl/jdqt56zx7nl6czhgp8qhdwd40000gn/T/pip-install-7odaoj4r/scipy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jl/jdqt56zx7nl6czhgp8qhdwd40000gn/T/pip-install-7odaoj4r/scipy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/jl/jdqt56zx7nl6czhgp8qhdwd40000gn/T/pip-wheel-8zcv76y9 --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /private/var/folders/jl/jdqt56zx7nl6czhgp8qhdwd40000gn/T/pip-install-7odaoj4r/scipy/
  Complete output (1015 lines):
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    FOUND:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
      library_dirs = ['/Users/michelle/anaconda/envs/py3/lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['/Users/michelle/anaconda/envs/py3/include']
  
    FOUND:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
      library_dirs = ['/Users/michelle/anaconda/envs/py3/lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['/Users/michelle/anaconda/envs/py3/include']
  
  Running from scipy source directory.
  non-existing path in 'scipy/integrate': 'quadpack.h'
  Splitting linalg.interpolative Fortran source files
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    FOUND:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
      library_dirs = ['/Users/michelle/anaconda/envs/py3/lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['/Users/michelle/anaconda/envs/py3/include']
  
    FOUND:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
      library_dirs = ['/Users/michelle/anaconda/envs/py3/lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['/Users/michelle/anaconda/envs/py3/include']
  
  non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse': 'sparsetools/sparsetools_impl.h'
  non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse': 'sparsetools/bsr_impl.h'
  non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse': 'sparsetools/csc_impl.h'
  non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse': 'sparsetools/csr_impl.h'
  non-existing path in 'scipy/sparse': 'sparsetools/other_impl.h'
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  creating build
  creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scipy
  building library "dfftpack" sources
  building library "fftpack" sources
  building library "mach" sources
  building library "quadpack" sources
  building library "odepack" sources
  building library "dop" sources
  building library "fitpack" sources
  building library "fwrappers" sources
  building library "odrpack" sources
  building library "minpack" sources
  building library "rootfind" sources
  building library "superlu_src" sources
  building library "arpack_scipy" sources
  building library "sc_c_misc" sources
  building library "sc_cephes" sources
  building library "sc_mach" sources
  building library "sc_amos" sources
  building library "sc_cdf" sources
  building library "sc_specfun" sources
  building library "statlib" sources
  building extension "scipy.cluster._vq" sources
  building extension "scipy.cluster._hierarchy" sources
  building extension "scipy.fftpack._fftpack" sources
  creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack
  creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src
  conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dct.c
  conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dst.c
  f2py options: []
  f2py: scipy/fftpack/fftpack.pyf
  Reading fortran codes...
    Reading file 'scipy/fftpack/fftpack.pyf' (format:free)
  Line #86 in scipy/fftpack/fftpack.pyf:"       /* Single precision version */ "
    crackline:2: No pattern for line
  Post-processing...
```

And so on. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: What operating system and python version are you using?

Comment: @VictoryOmole why would the operating system matter? I do think that the versions of all Python packages, and the Python version, could help though. I gave +1 because I feel that it's a good question, but I'm also voting to close it because most people will lack enough information to answer it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would probably be better answered on StackOverflow